# Arquillian can not deploy "big" WAR in JBOSS

Tags: jboss, war, jboss-arquillian

I am using JBOSS EAP 6.0.1. Everything worked fine. I inserted some dependencies into my project and now the deployment of every test fails. It seems like there is some sort of file size limit to the deployments if I use the @deployment annotation to build my war

**Problem:**
The @deployment method builds the war file. The arquillian files are deployed. Now the WAR file is being deployed. The jboss content folder holds the file "content8205106135070241895tmp" with exactly 16368KB. It does not matter if I delete one dependency, the filesize stays the same.
The test itself never really starts/finishes.

If I cancel the test in netbeans. I get the following message from jboss:

```
at       org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:123) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4-JBPAPP-10565.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018740: Einhõngen des Deployment-Contents fehlgeschlagen
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DeploymentRootMountProcessor.deploy(DeploymentRootMountProcessor.java:92) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4-JBPAPP-10565.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4-JBPAPP-10565.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    ... 5 more
 Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:158) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.unzip(VFSUtils.java:845)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZipExpanded(VFS.java:536)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZipExpanded(VFS.java:567)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentMountProvider$Factory$ServerDeploymentRepositoryImpl.mountDeploymentContent(DeploymentMountProvider.java:97) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4-JBPAPP-10565.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DeploymentRootMountProcessor.deploy(DeploymentRootMountProcessor.java:88) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4-JBPAPP-10565.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    ... 6 more
```

I have build an example project for the exception:

**pom.xml**

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>ArquillianExceptionTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>ArquillianExceptionTest</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-beta-3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-beta-3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-security-spi</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.16.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbosssx</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.16.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockftpserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>MockFtpServer</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.3.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-warp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.odt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cocoon</groupId>
        <artifactId>cocoon-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**JUnit class**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;

import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ArchivePath;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Node;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.Maven;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class NewEmptyJUnitTestDisabled {

public NewEmptyJUnitTestDisabled() {
}

@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeploymentWar() {
    File[] libs = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeAndTestDependencies().asFile();
    WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "mytest.war")
            .addAsWebInfResource("META-INF/beans.xml", "beans.xml");
    for (File file : libs) {
        war.addAsLibrary(file);
    }
    for (Map.Entry<ArchivePath, Node> entry : war.getContent().entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().toString().contains(".jar")) {
            System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString());
        }
    }
    return war;
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() {
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
}

@Test
public void emtyTest() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Nothing here to see");
}
}
```

I am using arquillian remote server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
<!--https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/JBoss+AS+7.1%2C+JBoss+EAP+6.0+-+Remote-->
<container qualifier="arquillian-jbossas-remote">
    <configuration>
        <property name="managementAddress">127.0.0.1</property>
        <property name="managementPort ">9999</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
</arquillian>
```

The project will build fine, but the junit test case will never finish. The deployment will be stuck at around 16,8 MB.

Comment: If there is a maximal size, it would be definitely bigger then 16MB. What happens if you deploy your application manually?

Comment: It deploys fine, if I do it manually.

Comment: What is your deployment protocol?

Comment: Example project inserted, to show the exception.

Comment: Do you have any update on this? I have the same problem. Tests run fine as long as the artifact won't get too big. Which isn't too unrealistic as soon as use maven dependency resolver... :-(

Answer (score 1):

did you checked this bug?
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=871413
Looks like the solution is to use "jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools" that is shipped with EAP6.0.1 Maven Repository.